# Finding The Odd One Out

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is the question:

> Which of the following is the odd one out?
>   $$ (A) \sqrt{2 \frac 7 9} \quad\quad (B) \sqrt{1 - \frac{32}{81}} \quad\quad (C) \sqrt{\frac{27}{243}} \quad\quad (D) \sqrt{3 \frac 1 4}$$

I cannot understand the question. On what basis do we have to find the odd one out.
Any help is appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: Did you try just computing each of them?

Comment: What do i need to do will computing them solve the problem??

Comment: Well, it's a pretty decent way to start. Just looking at them, I see three that simplify nicely and one that doesn't....

Comment: Ok then i shall try that thank you

Comment: Irrationality is actually quite common, why call it odd?

Comment: I think the answer is (D) ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is D. The rest have perfect squares for denominators and numerators except for D.

$$\sqrt{2\cdot\frac{7}{9}} = \sqrt{\frac{25}{9}}$$

$$\sqrt{1-\frac{32}{81}}= \sqrt{\frac{49}{81}}$$

$$\sqrt{\frac{27}{243}}$$ is obvious, one is $3^3$ and other $3^5$.

The last option has $13$ which is prime and can't have square roots.

Answer (score 1):

Various arguments are possible, but they all lead to (D): you could argue that the first three fractions under the square roots are perfect squares, while (D) is not; or that they have denominators divisible by $9$, which (D) doen't have; or that they have odd denominators, while in (D) it's even. The exercise was conceived in such a way as for (D) to "shout" at you.

These exercises do not test your mathematical knowledge, they rather test your psychological abilities for doing mathematics: in this case, do you see what is obvious in these formulae? (Of course, you will find plenty of idiots who will try to argue that "obviousness" is subjective; ignore them.)